# How to render the image in a blog post from a database?

Tags: database, django-rest-framework, development-environment

Pardon me, if it sounds like a noob doubt

I am making a blog website, where I am storing the text in MySQL DB, and planning to store image as a url, since otherwise it will make db bulky. So hosting image elsewhere seems to be a reasonable choice.

**What I wanted to know is:**

**1.** As soon as user uploads the image(s) in his blog post somewhere, where should I upload that image and how to get the url of that image, so that I can store it in db.

**2**. How to render that image when fetching from the database at particular place. What I mean by this is, may be the image cane uploaded at top, somewhere in the middle or maybe at the end or the mixture of some or many.

**3.** And should I create a create a different column to store that image link, if so, then if the user has uploaded multiple images then should I store all under image column of db. If so, then how to tackle my problem #2

Help me, by pointing me towards right direction.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

User uploaded files are usually placed in a `media` directory inside your project. You can configure it using `MEDIA_ROOT` in django settings. And the file's relative path is stored in the database.

For example if you have this config in your settings: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_dir/')`

The uploaded file is stored in this path: `/path/to/project/media_dir/my_file.csv` and your db record has `my_file.csv` as the value for your FileField.

It would also help you to read this article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/